# How can I add custom items to the Apple menu?

Tags: macos, mojave, menu-bar

I would like to add shortcuts to open apps such as Terminal, Google Chrome, Launchpad etc., or to open a folder as a sub-menu.

Is it possible to do so? If yes, how do I do it?

I am running macOS Mojave.

Comment: What's wrong with putting them in the Dock? That's what it's for.

Comment: Just for clarity, when you say "Apple menu" are you referring only to the actual Apple Menu that has the  symbol, or are you referring to the Menu Bar in general?

Comment: Yes, I mean the  menu on the far left, which is always the same independently of the front app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Apple menu is not designed to be customized by anyone. However, I would recommend XMenu (available on the Mac App Store, and also [download from here](https://www.devontechnologies.com/products/freeware.html)).

This handy little app will give you menus in the menu bar that you can customize, either to include the entire Applications folder as a drop-down menu, or you can add aliases to 'Favorite' items.

Comment: Thanks for the advise.  XMenu is really great! It covers all my needs.   I just wish I could position it left from the .

Comment: Updated web address: https://www.devontechnologies.com/apps/freeware

Answer (score -1):

The Apple menu depends on the App displayed in front, to display usefull command for this app.

It can't be customized, or you have to create your own app and when it'll be in front you can put whatever shortcuts you want.

Otherwise, you can put any shortcut you want in the Dock.

Comment: The Apple menu is not App-dependent. All the others are.